# Removing all the rows of DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I want to delete all the rows of DefaultTable. I found two common ways to delete them on internet, but none of them works in my case because those methods does not exist in my DefaultTableModel. I wonder why. My code for using DefaultTableModel is

```java
DefaultTableModel Table = (DefaultTableModel) Table.getModel();
```

One way to delete is

```java
Table.removeRow(Table.getRowCount() - 1);
```

but this removerow method does not exist in my DefaultTableModel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why complicating simple things, but removes must be iterative,

```
if (myTableModel.getRowCount() > 0) {
    for (int i = myTableModel.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        myTableModel.removeRow(i);
    }
}
```

Code example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class RemoveAddRows extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Object[] columnNames = {"Type", "Company", "Shares", "Price"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50)},
        {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25)},
        {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35)},
        {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00)}
    };
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    public RemoveAddRows() {

        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                int firstRow = 0;
                int lastRow = table.getRowCount() - 1;
                int width = 0;
                if (row == lastRow) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (row == firstRow) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.blue);
                } else {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(table.getBackground());
                }
                /*if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
                String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
                c.setBackground("Buy".equals(type) ? Color.GREEN : Color.YELLOW);
                }
                if (isRowSelected(row) && isColumnSelected(column)) {
                ((JComponent) c).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
                }*/
                return c;
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Remove all rows");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
                    for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                        model.removeRow(i);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("model.getRowCount() --->" + model.getRowCount());
            }
        });
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Add new rows");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Object[] data0 = {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50)};
                model.addRow(data0);
                Object[] data1 = {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25)};
                model.addRow(data1);
                Object[] data2 = {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35)};
                model.addRow(data2);
                Object[] data3 = {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00)};
                model.addRow(data3);
                System.out.println("model.getRowCount() --->" + model.getRowCount());
            }
        });
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.add(button1);
        southPanel.add(button2);
        add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RemoveAddRows frame = new RemoveAddRows();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason not the complicate simple things is to avoid mistakes like you did here: the if statement is redundant, it does not remove the row at index 0 and it unnecessarily fires an event for each row.

Comment: @Walter Laan thanks for notified stupid mistake, with rest I simple disagreed, same with an answers here,

Comment: Answers below are simpler, namely using `setRowCount(0);`

Answer (score 45):

You can set the row count to 0.
`setRowCount(0)`

Quote from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setRowCount%28int%29):

> ```
> public void setRowCount(int rowCount)
> ```
>
> Sets the number of rows in the model. If the new size is greater than
> the current size, new rows are added to the end of the model If the
> new size is less than the current size, all rows at index rowCount and
> greater are discarded.

But as you can't find `removeRow` either I suspect you haven't typed you model variable as `DefaultTableModel` perhaps, maybe just `TableModel`?

In that case cast your `TableModel` to `DefaultTableModel` like this:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
```

Comment: I have already been using this same typecasting but still this method doesn't exist

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried this
This works for me..

```
defaultTableModel.setRowCount(0);
```

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you read the [javadoc of DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)?

> public void removeRow(int row)
>
> Removes the row at row from the model. Notification of the row being
>   removed will be sent to all the listeners.
>
> public void setDataVector(Vector dataVector,
>                             Vector columnIdentifiers)
>
> Replaces the current dataVector instance variable with the new
>   Vector of rows, dataVector.
>
> public void setRowCount(int rowCount)
>
> Sets the number of rows in the model. If the new size is greater than
>   the current size, new rows are added to the end of the model If the
>   new size is less than the current size, all rows at index rowCount and
>   greater are discarded.

Answer (score 3):

Simply keep removing the table model's first row until there are no more rows left.

```
// clean table
DefaultTableModel myTableModel = (DefaultTableModel) this.myjTable.getModel(); 
while (myTableModel.getRowCount() > 0) {
       myTableModel.removeRow(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ypu can write a method

```
public void clearTable()
  {
    getTableModel().setRowCount(0);
  }
```

then call this method from the place that you need to clear the table