# How to remove rows in JTable before populating new data into the table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm populating data from my database into my JTable. After I add new data and press Refresh button, I want to remove the existing row displayed on table before retrieving the new data. How can I remove the existing row?

Here is the original table with data [a,1].

[image: Original]

This is the table after I add new data [b,1] and press refresh button. The original data [a,1] is still shown in the table:

[image: After insert]

```
JButton refreshButton = new JButton("Refresh");
refreshButton.setBounds(188, 248, 101, 23);
panel.add(refreshButton);

refreshButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{                        
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
    int rowCount = model.getRowCount(); 

    for (int x = 0; x <=rowCount; x++)
    {
        model.removeRow(x);
    }


        try
        {                       
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/watchlist","root","root");

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM watchlist";
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();    


            int columns = md.getColumnCount();  

            while (rs.next())
            {   
                Vector row = new Vector(columns);

                for (int i=1; i <= columns; i++)
                {
                    row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );              
                    System.out.println( rs.getObject(i).toString());        
                }                           

                data.addElement(row);   

                table.revalidate(); 
                table.repaint();
                panel.repaint();

            } // end while  

        } // end try

        catch (Exception e){
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: You need to clear the table model in refresh method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I saw this question,

1) search for `ResultsetTableModel / TableFromDatabase` (better)

- (if Database Connection (so hard and lazy action) isn't closed during Applications lifecycle)

a) replace `JTable` contents

b) works with embeded Db of database placed in intranet immediatelly

- dis

all processes is durring EDT, then GUI waiting for SQL statement

for most code examples required to move `Xxx.close` to the finally block

2) most complex workaround you have to use `SwingWorker`, better and easiest way is to load data from `Runnable#Thread`

3) you can [remove row(s) from TableModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10414459/714968),

Comment: Thanks mKorblel. I'm using the 3rd option of removing rows, it's working fine.

Comment: glad to help you, but you choosed wrong option I still this that you have to use [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) instead

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove the row (see DefaultTableModel.removeRow)
or put the new data into a new table model, and replace the table's table model with JTable.setModel()

Comment: I'm able to remove one row with model.removeRow(0); .. How can I delete all the available rows?

Answer (score 1):

Upon refreshing button, call the following:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,col);
model.removeRow(1); // first row in this case
```

In this case you need to manage to get the data , columns and the row count.Data is your actual data, col is the number of columns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! it helped me remove the first row of data. What if I have more than 1 data available? I've added a loop to retrieve the rowCount of the table. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @LilyT, you need to get the rowCount then insde a for loop, call model.removeRow(i);

Comment: i already inserted a loop with the model.removeRow inside (i've added it in the code above). i've got this error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 1

Comment: @LilyT, which means that index is more than the table row count.paste the code here.

Comment: DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
    int rowCount = model.getRowCount(); 

    for (int x = 0; x <=rowCount; x++)
    {
        model.removeRow(x);
    }

Comment: @LilyT, the for loop should be for (int x = 0; x <rowCount; x++) { model.removeRow(x); } .Now try this.

Comment: i still get this error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 1

Comment: the link posted by mKorbel seemed similar. can you check it out?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10414459/714968

Comment: The solution from the link works! Thanks for your guidance UNNI :)

Comment: Just to have the answers all in one place in case someone comes looking...

* The correct answer is DefaultTableModel.setRowCount(0)

* The problem with the loop discussed above is the usual noob attempt to remove everything from a list, one at a time - you either have to start with the last item, and count down, or remove item zero as many times as you have items. Otherwise, you wind up referencing item indexes that no longer exist (hence the Exception)

So, either:

for(int i = rowCount -1; i >= 0; --i) { model.removeRow(i); }

or 

for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) { model.removeRow(0); }

Answer (score -2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTIIk.jpg)

this method  i used to populte data in any jTbale

### it clear jtable (refresh ) jtable befor populte new data

this line cleare jatble befor populate data

### mytable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(null, colname));

public static  void FilltableV(JTable mytable, String sql){
    Connection   con = null;

```
    Statement Cmd = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
try {


    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/alserg", "root", "");

    sql="SELECT * FROM products";
    Cmd=con.createStatement();
    rs=Cmd.executeQuery(sql);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmt=rs.getMetaData();
    int colno =rsmt.getColumnCount();
    Vector colname =new Vector();
    DefaultTableModel mytab =new  DefaultTableModel();
    Vector rows =new Vector();
    for(int i=1 ;i< colno;++i){
        colname.addElement(rsmt.getColumnName(i));
        mytab.setColumnIdentifiers(colname);

    }

    while (rs.next()){
        rows= new Vector();
        for (int j=1;j<colno;++j){
            rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));


        }
        mytab.addRow(rows);
        mytable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(null, colname));
        mytable.setModel(mytab);



    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(products.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
finally {
    try {
        rs.close();
        Cmd.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AlseragLang.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: The basic idea here is OK.  You can use `table.setModel()` to apply a new set of data.  But the code is not very clear.

Comment: i want to refere to how to refresh jtable in simple way and i made this method to show how to refresh jtable and you use it with any jtable

Comment: the fist line of code out of code area 
public static void FilltableV(JTable mytable, String sql){ Connection con = null;
this method dos'nt nead more than to par jtable name, sql query 
and i focus on clear jtable by setmodel it self 
and by add one line 
 mytable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(null, colname));

Comment: to claer rows before populte new data by next line