# JTable inside a JScrollPane not showing up properly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jscrollpane

I am working on a the GUI of a piece of code that I have been patching together. I am stuck at this part of the program where I would like a datafile the user chooses to be displayed in a `JTable` in a preview manner (i.e. the user should not be able to edit the data on the table).

With a button click from Experiment Parameters tab (see screenshot below), I create and run a "PreviewAction" which creates a new tab, and fills it up with the necessary components. Below is the code for `DataPreviewAction`. **EDIT:** I also posted a [self-contained, minimal version](http://pastebin.com/HxTZyMiW) of this that mimics the conditions in the real project, and exhibits the same behaviour.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

private JPanel panel1;
private JTabbedPane tabs;
private JButton runButton;

public MyFrame() {
    tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    runButton = new JButton("go!");
    runButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            runButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    panel1.add(runButton);
    tabs.addTab("first tab", panel1);
    this.add(tabs);
    pack();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager
                .getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private void runButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    /*
     * Normally there is more stuff happening here but this much will do for
     * the sake of example
     */
    List<String[]> data = new LinkedList<String[]>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
        data.add(new String[] { "entry1", "value1", "value2", "value3" });

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DataPreviewAction(data, tabs));
}

public class DataPreviewAction implements Runnable {

    private JTabbedPane contentHolder;
    private List<String[]> data;

    public DataPreviewAction(List<String[]> data, JTabbedPane comp) {
        this.contentHolder = comp;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        DefaultTableModel previewModel = new DefaultTableModel() {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        for (String[] datarow : data) {
            previewModel.addRow(Arrays.copyOf(datarow, datarow.length,
                    Object[].class));
        }

        JTable table = new JTable(previewModel);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("A button"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(
                "Some description for the awesome table below "));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("another button"));

        JScrollPane tablePanel = new JScrollPane(table);
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container.add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentHolder.addTab("Preview", container);
        contentHolder.validate();
        contentHolder.repaint();
    }
}
}
```

There are at least two problems here:

1. The `JTable` (or the `JScrollPane`) does not render at all
2. The `JScrollPane` is not as wide as the frame itself, I have no idea why

I am not all that good in Swing so I might be missing something fundamental. I have checked that the datafile is read properly, and the data model contains the right amount of rows (1000+). SO the table should not be empty.

Suggestions?

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: And from where and how you are calling this code?

Comment: @Sanjeev  Both your questions would be answered if the OP added a MCTaRE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson added a link to pastebin, a single class, that pretty much mimics the same conditions as the real code, minus a whole chunk of other components and action listeners etc

Comment: *"added a link to pastebin.."*  If it is a MCTaRE, it should be short enough to edit into the question.

Comment: okay... i'll edit the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the footsteps of mKorbel I ended up doing some debugging. I am providing it here in case others run into the same problem.

It felt quite odd that the table looked OK when the underlying `DataModel` was supplied a data matrix upon initialisation

```
private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
```

but it would **not show up properly** when created with the empty constructor

```
private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel()
```

and adding rows later with `model.addRow(Object[] row);`

I started look through the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.java), and it turns out with the empty constructor the number of rows and columns for the model (private fields) is initiated to 0 and **not updated properly** afterwards. I noticed this while debugging since my tables had the dimension of 1370 x 0, which of course does not display properly.

Since I do not want to hardcode the number of rows/cols in advance the best course of action was to convert my "rows" to a matrix and provide the data to the `model` via constructor (much like mKorbel did). Here comes the fun part, if you want to supply the data then you need to supply the column names as well. THe fact that you have to have column names is counter-intuitive (IMHO), what happens if you dont have/need headers? The data is already in a table form, so I dont understand why column names is so important.

At any rate the following code renders the table at least:

```
String[] colNames = new String[data[1].length];
for(int i=0; i<colNames.length; i++)
    colNames[i] = "C" + i;

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,colNames){
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
        return false;
    }};
```

---

I am accepting this because it points to the origin of the problem, but I would not be able to pinpoint the problem without mKorbel's answer, so give the upvote to his/her answer :)

Comment: This fixed my problem!

Answer (score 6):

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.add(new JButton("A button"));
buttonPanel.add(new JLabel("Some description for the awesome table below "));
buttonPanel.add(new JButton("another button"));

JScrollPane tablePanel = new JScrollPane(table);
JPanel container = new JPanel();
container.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
container.add(tablePanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
contentHolder.addTab("Preview", container);
    //contentHolder.validate(); <- NO good
    //contentHolder.repaint();  <- --"---
}
```

- [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) uses [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) (implemented in API, acceptiong only `PreferredSize`, by default isn't resizable), correct output as is demonstrated in attn image, you have to change default [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for `JPanel` to [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), then code lines

.

```
container.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
container.add(tablePanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

- will expands [JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) and can be works as you expecting, but I think `tablePanel` should be placed in `CENTER` area

EDIT:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel1;
    private JTabbedPane tabs;
    private JButton runButton;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private String[] columnNames = {"Nama", "Nim", "IP", "Hapus Baris ke"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"igor", "B01_125-358", "1.124.01.125", true},
        {"lenka", "B21_002-242", "21.124.01.002", true},
        {"peter", "B99_001-358", "99.124.01.001", false},
        {"zuza", "B12_100-242", "12.124.01.100", true},
        {"jozo", "BUS_011-358", "99.124.01.011", false},
        {"nora", "B09_154-358", "9.124.01.154", false},
        {"xantipa", "B01_001-358", "1.124.01.001", false},};
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 3:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };

    public MyFrame() {
        tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        runButton = new JButton("go!");
        runButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                //
            }
        });
        panel1.add(runButton);
        tabs.addTab("first tab", panel1);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("A button"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JLabel("Some description for the awesome table below "));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("another button"));
        JScrollPane tablePanel = new JScrollPane(table);
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container.add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        tabs.addTab("Preview", container);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(tabs);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT 2nd. e.g.

[image]

from code (included your idea about to fill data to model)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel1;
    private JTabbedPane tabs;
    private JButton runButton;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private String[] columnNames = {"Nama", "Nim", "IP", "Hapus Baris ke"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"igor", "B01_125-358", "1.124.01.125", "true"},
        {"lenka", "B21_002-242", "21.124.01.002", "true"},
        {"peter", "B99_001-358", "99.124.01.001", "false"},
        {"zuza", "B12_100-242", "12.124.01.100", "true"},
        {"jozo", "BUS_011-358", "99.124.01.011", "false"},
        {"nora", "B09_154-358", "9.124.01.154", "false"},
        {"xantipa", "B01_001-358", "1.124.01.001", "false"},};
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 3:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };

    public MyFrame() {
        tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        runButton = new JButton("go!");
        runButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                List<String[]> data = new LinkedList<String[]>();
                for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                    data.add(new String[]{"entry1", "value1", "value2", "value3"});
                }
                for (String[] datarow : data) {
                    model.addRow(Arrays.copyOf(datarow, datarow.length, Object[].class));
                }
            }
        });
        panel1.add(runButton);
        tabs.addTab("first tab", panel1);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("A button"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JLabel("Some description for the awesome table below "));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("another button"));
        JScrollPane tablePanel = new JScrollPane(table);
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container.add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        tabs.addTab("Preview", container);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(tabs);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing `LayoutManager` helped with scaling the area for `ScrollPane`, but neither that nor moving the alignment to CENTER makes a difference for the rendering.

Comment: example for [SSCCE, MCVE, MCTRE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10414459/714968), then something will be possible to suggest (JFrame???, JTabbedPane, setPreferredScrollableViewportSize), otherwise everything is left out of the MilkyWay

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, could you perhaps clarify?

Comment: yes, the example code above runs on my machine.. the  imports are missing from the code above, I just realised.. I'll just add them

Comment: ignore my previous comment, what do you really want to do, 1. add a new tab to JTabbedPane or 2. change data for JTable

Comment: JTabbedPane created inside DataPreviewAction never is added to JFrame, is local variable without any effect(s)

Comment: add new tab to JTabbedPane, no change to data on JTable, just load a datamodel in to JTable and display it.

Comment: JTabbedPane is not created inside DataPreviewAction and the tab is indeed created, the contents of the tab however are not, see: [screenshot for SSCCE](http://i.imgur.com/j7I5VPz.png)

Comment: JTable with data is added to JTabbedPane (local variable in DataPreviewAction) and hasn't any link to private JTabbedPane tabs; created ad added to JFrame.

Comment: issue is in parameter DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) see my edit

Comment: So I need to have some data already in the table in order to add more!? That doesn't make any sense... If I don't have any arguments to the `DefaultTableModel` constructor then I should have a 0x0 table, then expand it with as many rows as I have, i.e. when the user clicks the "go!" button. Why is that not the case with my code? (BTW: shall we remove some of the less relevant comments above, to minimise clutter and confusion?)

Comment: I debug you code before, then I post result (best ilustration is in my 2nd. edit)